# How to know how many mils are currently google map is showing

Tags: asp.net, javascript, google-maps

i have got center of map using map.getCenter(); and i got current zoom of google map using getZoom(); please tell me how can i calculate/get current show mils area in google map. i am using asp.net and javascript.

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you need it in mils? I've rarely had to use mils and only really with things too small to see in google map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `GMap2.getBounds()` you can get the visible rectangular region of the map view.
Then using these coordinates you can construct a `GPolygon` object and calculate the area in square meters using `GPolygon.getArea()` function. Then convert given area to mils (1 meter = 39 370.0787 mils).

Comment: and what about Zoom? is (1 meter = 39 370.0787 mils) same for zoom?

Comment: What you mean? map.getZoom() function return current zoom level.

Comment: please tell how to do it.. i am not able to implement it... either give me some sample code or refer me to any site

Answer (score 1):

the `GLatLng` object has a `distanceFrom` function that takes another `GLatLng`. The map has `getBounds` from which you'll be able to get the corners of interest, and check the distance between them.